# Optimization of a MySQL view

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, query-optimization

I want to join two MySQL tables and store it as a view, so I can address this view in a application in stead of querying two tables. But this view occurs to be extremely slow.

This are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE spectrumsets (
    setid INT(11) NOT NULL,
    timestampdt INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    timestampd INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    timestampt INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    device INT(11) NOT NULL,
    methodname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (setid),
    UNIQUE INDEX setid_idx (setid),
    UNIQUE INDEX timestamp_device_idx (timestampd, timestampt, device),
    INDEX device_fk (device),
    INDEX timestampd_idx (timestampd),
    CONSTRAINT device_fk FOREIGN KEY (device)
        REFERENCES spectrumdevices (deviceid)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE spectrumdata (
    valueid INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    spectrumset INT(11) NOT NULL,
    wavelength DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    intensity DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (valueid),
    INDEX spectrumset_idx (spectrumset),
    CONSTRAINT spectrumset_fk FOREIGN KEY (spectrumset)
        REFERENCES spectrumsets (setid)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

And this is my view:

```
SELECT spectrumsets.timestampd,spectrumsets.timestampt,spectrumsets.device,
    spectrumdata.wavelength,spectrumdata.intensity
FROM spectrumdata INNER JOIN spectrumsets ON spectrumdata.spectrumset=
    spectrumsets.setid
WHERE spectrumdata.wavelength>0 
ORDER BY spectrumsets.timestampd,spectrumsets.timestampt,spectrumsets.device,
    spectrumdata.wavelength
```

A `select count(*)` on my machine takes 385.516 seconds and results into 82923705 records, so a rather large dataset

I already found this [link](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker/) but still don't fully understand what's wrong.

UPDATE:

`EXPLAIN` gives this results:

```
"id","select_type","table","type","possible_keys","key","key_len","ref","rows","Extra"
"1","SIMPLE","spectrumsets","index","PRIMARY,setid_idx","timestamp_device_idx","12",NULL,"327177","Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort"
"1","SIMPLE","spectrumdata","ref","spectrumset_idx","spectrumset_idx","4","primprod.spectrumsets.setid","130","Using where"
```

Comment: Does running `analyse table spectrumdata spectrumsets` make any difference?

Comment: What's your buffer_pool_size? Looks like the dataset doesn't fit in memory so InnoDB is probably raping your disk while doing a full table scan.

Comment: @nevillek I added the EXPLAIN results but don't know how to read this. I've to dig into this

Comment: What does `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer_pool%';` say?

Comment: @n.b. innodb_buffer_pool_size = 134217728

Comment: @bohemian What exactly do you mean?

Comment: You're running with default settings for innodb_buffer_pool_size (128MB). This variable is usually good to have on high settings, at about 80% of your system's memory. That's why larger databases based on innodb are being installed at systems with 16GB+ memory. 399 seconds is quite a bit, it should be in rages of several seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explain suggests that the query is hitting the indices for the join (which is good), but then using a temporary table and file sort for the rest of the query.

This is for two reasons:

- the where clause isn't hitting the index
- the order by clause isn't hitting the index

In a comment, you say that removing the where clause has lead to a big improvement; that suggests you need the compound index on spectrumset, wavelength, assuming wavelength has a decent number of possible values (if it's just 10 values, an index may not do anything).

If you leave the "order by" clause out of your view, it should go a lot faster - and there's a good case for letting sort order be determined by the query extracting data, not the view. I'm guessing most queries will be very selective about the data - limiting to a few timestamps; by embedding the order by in the view, you pay the price for sorting every time.

If you really must have the "order by" in the view, create an index that includes all fields in the order of the "order by", with the join at the front. For instance:

UNIQUE INDEX timestamp_device_idx (set_id, timestampd, timestampt, device),

Comment: +1. This is the right answer, but MySQL 5.0+ can use more than one index using [index merge](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html). I would remove that statement to the contrary or clarify. Also, for that compound index, put the column that uses a range (in this case it's the wavelength column, see `WHERE wavelength > 0`) last in the index because using a range against an index invalidates the remaining part. Other than that, put the columns with the highest cardinality first.

Comment: Did some testing: removing the ORDER BY clause reduces the performance time of around 385 seconds to about 285 seconds, but removing also the WHERE clause to about 48 seconds! So I think I really need to move the ORDER BY clause to the calling application, but also the WHERE clause. Not really a problem in my case, but I still don't fully understand what's going in :-( Will have something to with innodb_buffer_pool_size but also the construction of the SQL statement of the view.

Comment: That's a really good indication that it's the where clause that's causing the problem; I'll edit the answer accordingly.